# 5 stars on Android Coin Dozer?

Tags: ios, android, coin-dozer

I've seen on the iPhone version of Coin Dozer, it is possible to change the 4 stars into 5 stars (meaning you can use coins quicker).

Is this possible on Android? And if so how do I unlock it?

Comment: Man, I searched Google looking for the answer and got this. What are the odds? I wanna know too.

Comment: Is it different than the iPhone version? I only played the iPhone version and there you can drop 5 coins at a time if you have a reserve of 50 coins or more

Comment: @JohnoBoy - Ah with Android, I've got about 80 coins and still only 4 stars. Perhaps the versions are just slightly different?

Comment: I have 600+ coins and still no five stars - I doubt you will get 5 stars just by accumulating coins.

Comment: I'm not sure what triggers it but I have noticed that every now and then it will let me do 5 coins (showing 5 stars) but it seems to randomly disappear/reappear...

Comment: I get to drop 5 coins sometimes but not always its weird I noticed the other day I had 5 stars but. Like I said it comes and goes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible on Android. These screenshots were taken this morning from my S3.

When below 50 coins, only 4 stars are available:[image]

But when you have 50 or more coins, 5 stars are available:[image]

It may have been added in a recent update, but the Android version certainly can have 5 stars.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can safely say the answer is no. There is no information on the internet to support an increase in stars at any level.

From personal experience, I have played the game to a near 100 level and have had thousands of coins and the number of coins available to drop at one time has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm at 8000 coins on android and level 192, so no.